# How to share my own custom fucntions on AWS lambda nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I Currently have a project in AWS with several lambda functions, most of the functions in NodeJS, I want to know if is there a way to create a lambda layer with **my own code functions** that I use in different lambdas without publish it in npm, I already search in old questions in stack [question-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65888704/using-custom-nodejs-function-in-a-aws-lambda-layer) [question-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61638895/aws-lambda-nodejs-custom-layer), but these were not answered

Thanks for help!

Comment: Yes, you can create a layer with your common code and share it between your functions. There is official AWS documentation about how to do this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html

Comment: but my functions didn't generate this folder `nodejs/node_modules`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. create a folder in your local machine called nodejs
2. put your "shared" logic in that folder like /nodejs/shared.js
3. you can zip this nodejs folder and upload as a layer
4. in your lambda code require the shared.js as `const shared = require('/opt/nodejs/shared.js'`)

Links:

- Lambda layers: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html
- Detailed guide: https://explainexample.com/computers/aws/aws-lambda-layers-node-app
- Using layers with SAM: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverlessrepo/latest/devguide/sharing-lambda-layers.html